# Calculate difference in days between successive pandas datetime values within same ID group

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the difference in days between successive datetime value within the same ID.

Here's my dataframe and codes:

```
d = {'ID': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
'date': ['10/1/2010','10/1/2010','10/10/2010','10/10/2010','1/1/2001','3/1/2001','3/1/2001','6/1/2001','1/1/1990','3/1/1990','6/1/1990']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['Days'] = df.groupby('ID')['date'].diff().fillna('')
df
```

However, I get '0 days' when the successive dates are identical to each other.

For example, there are two '2010-10-10' that are a member of ID 'a'; the first row with '2010-10-10' has a value of '9 days' but the second row return '0 days'. My goal is to write a code so that both have '9 days'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace 0 with *nan* and then do a forward fill:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df['Days'] = (df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False)
                .apply(lambda g: g['date'].diff().replace(0, np.nan).ffill()))
df
```

[image]